# Delegate.CreateDelegate without prototype

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Right now, I have to do this

```
private delegate void set(int obj); //declare the prototype

...
Delegate delegate1 = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(set), new testObject(), props[0].GetSetMethod());

((set)delegate1)(1);
```

Is there a way to CreateDelegate without that prototype and call it with any parameter? GetSetMethod() returns a very specific MethodInfo that takes a specific type as an argument.

Thanks

Comment: It's for my earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297637/c-property-system. Just exploring an alternative.

Comment: By the way, props[0] is a PropertyInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 you can use `Expression.GetActionType`:

```
    Type setterType = Expression.GetActionType(props[0].PropertyType);
    Delegate delegate1 = Delegate.CreateDelegate(setterType,
        new testObject(), props[0].GetSetMethod()
    );
```

Or if you want an open delegate (i.e. to any `testObject` instance, not bound to the new one):

```
    Type setterType = Expression.GetActionType(
        props[0].DeclaringType, props[0].PropertyType);
    Delegate delegate1 = Delegate.CreateDelegate(setterType,
        null, props[0].GetSetMethod()
    );
```

However; note that you'd have to use these delegates via `DynamicInvoke`, which is much slower than using a fully typed delegate via `Invoke`.

Another option (for this scenario) is to bind to a delegate that takes `object`, and use casting **inside** the delegate - via perhaps some [fancy generics](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx), a compiled `Expression`, or custom IL.

Comment: He can also just pass `typeof(Action<int>)` to `CreateDelegate`. :)

Comment: The above is because I don't want to write a delegate prototype for each possible type (int, double, ... user defined types).

Comment: Ah yea I benchmarked DynamicInvoke. It takes 5000+ ms when the direct delegate takes ~15ms. I was hoping for a direct-call delegate that will auto-cast to the required type of the Set method.

Comment: @280Z28 - I was intentionally leaving it for the most general case where all we have is a PropertyInfo.